# image upload not uploading

Tags: php, image, file

I am trying to upload an image to my server, now the code is very straight forward, but it never passes the if test, it always goes straight to the else statement and executes the code there, i.e; invalid file. Below if the form code...

```
<form action="take.php" method="get" onsubmit='return chequer()' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image1"/>
</form>
```

And the php script to upload the image is below, which of course is in the take.php file:

```
if ($_GET["image"] == Null)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO postable (description, dated, posterid, country, state, city, area)
VALUES
('$_GET[Desc]',NOW(),'$row[0]','$_GET[Country]','$_GET[State]','$_GET[City]','$_GET[area]')";
}
else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO postable (description, dated, image, posterid, country, state, city, area)
VALUES
('$_GET[Desc]',NOW(),'$_GET[image]','$row[0]','$_GET[Country]','$_GET[State]','$_GET[City]','$_GET[area]')";
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image1"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["image1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["image1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["image1"]["size"] < 65536)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["image1"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image1"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image1"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image1"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image1"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["image1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image1"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: And what is the error? Or you expect us to read the code and figure out? Check for error logs!

Comment: It does not give me an error, all it does is fail the if test and go straight to the else statement and executes the echo statement there... The code is not complicated in any case...

Comment: did you changed to `POST` like @Anup Singh said ?

Answer (score 3):

to upload a file your form method should always be POST so convert GET to POST in form method

Answer (score 0):

check that which type of file you are trying to upload.use:

```
echo $_FILES["image1"]["type"];
```

because some time the image types is different which we are trying to upload.or you can try another image.